# Portfolio Diversity : invest $4000 into one account or $1000 into 4 accounts?

Tags: income, portfolio, diversification

I have a simple question : regardless of portfolio diversity and how it could be a more stable source on income, i'd like to know what system will produce more money ?

1. $4000 into one account symbol
2. $1000 into 4 accounts symbols
3. or is it the same and why?

of course I suppose symbols are not correlated and that it depends of the symbol used, but *in theory*

Comment: Well the rate of return on $4,000 is so minimal in anything other than a high risk stock that this question is academic at best. If you are deciding on high risk stocks then do 1,000 in each.

Comment: what do you mean by 'symbol' ???

Comment: symbol = EURUSD, AAPL, BIX etc

Comment: yes it's an academic question. I could've used 1 million instead of $1000. The main questions is : does separating the money into different trading systems will produce more money than if I use only 1 system? Does not *have* to be high risk

Comment: trading systems != symbols, symbols != accounts. Can you please decide what you're asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spread money/investment across different accounts for different reasons:

- Some types of accounts may have different level of protection (250K FDIC protection)
- Others have annual limits (401K, IRA...)
- Some have different rules regarding withdraws and taxes. (retirement vs non-retirement accounts)

All this is in addition to diversification reasons. Investing all your money into one stock, bond, Mutual fund, ETF is risky if that one segment of the economy/market suffers.

There is a drawback to diversification of accounts. Some have minimum amounts and fee structures. In the original question you asked about 1,000 per account. That may mean that some accounts may be closed to you. In other cases they will charge a higher percentage for fees for small accounts. Those issues would disappear long before you hit the 1,000,000 per account you mentioned in your comment.

One problem can occur with having too much diversification. Having dozens of funds could mean that the overlap between the funds might result in over investing in a segment because you didn't realize that one stock segment appeared in 1/3 of the funds.